# Замена строки через регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как заменить все переходы на новуя строку внутри строки на пробел, если эти переходы находятся внутри двойных кавычек?
То есть строка

```
Строка"строка

строка"строкастрокастрока

строкастрокастрока
```

Должна быть заменена на следующую

```
Строка"строка строка"строкастрокастрока

строкастрокастрока
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - можно разбить строку на части по кавычкам, после чего провести замену в нечётных частях и собрать обратно. Код примерно следующий:

```
String text = "Строка\"строка\n\nстрока\"строкастрокастрока\n\nстрокастрокастрока";
String[] tokens = text.split("\"");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if ((i & 1) == 1) {
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace('\n', ' ');
    }
}
String result = String.join("\"", tokens);
System.out.println(result);
```

Результат:

```
Строка"строка  строка"строкастрокастрока

строкастрокастрока
```

При необходимости можно заменить несколько пробелов одним. Также, в случае, если в качестве переноса строк используется сочетание `\r\n`, то заменять следует именно его.